# in angular, how to avoid users without some roles rights to see, to download, restricted screens?

Tags: angular

Using routes guards it is possible to restrict access but users without rights still have access to source files and they can see the structures, is it possible to avoid even if the access to download the restricted sources based on roles using Angular?

Comment: Rout Guards prevent you from entering the route, if you'd like to prevent access to links or download actions, you'd have to do it per element. You might want to share some of what you have already done and ask a more specific question about something not working as you need.

Comment: I might be wrong (I *hope* I'm wrong), but I fear you're trying to achieve security by not giving the web browser the code used to retrieve the data, etc. If the API calls to the data aren't secured, your app isn't secure regardless of whether or not the front end is accessible.

Comment: @JSmart523, I'm not worried about data, but the structure of screens used by system admin users, I want only admin users have access to the screen, even without data. If you open inspector in the browser and go to network, you have access to screens "blocked" by route guards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `canActivate` and `data` in route defination of restricated screens.

In Router file:

```
{ 
   path: 'restricted-screen', 
   component: RestrictedScreenComponent,
   canActivate: RoleGuard,
   data: {roles: ['SuperAdmin', ...]}
}
```

And RoleGuard code will be:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    let roles = route.data.roles as Array<string>;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It only block access to "live" routes, with data, on the fly, but if you open inspector in the browser and go to network tab, everybody has access to templates and can interpret all fields from screens.